# Guessing the correct character and position in string

Tags: python

I'm very new to coding and I am struggling with one of my first codes.

I'm wanting to create a *word guessing* game, where the user guesses the character and position of several letters at a time.  The step I'm stuck on can be summed up:

1. guess and selected word inputed;
2. check if two letter guess is in selected word's first 2 characters (+10 points per correct letter); and
3. check if the two letter guess is in the correct positions of selected word(+50 points per correct letter).

I cannot seem to find a way to do this.  This is what I have so far. I want to continue the rest of the code by myself, however, it's incredibly difficult if I can't get past the first step!

```
def compute_score(guess,position,word):
        """ Doc string """

        score = 0
        right_position_value = 100
        wrong_position_value = 20
        guess = input()
        position = pos for char in guess
        word_position = pos for char in word

        for char in word:
            if char in guess:
                    score += 10
            if position == word_position:
                    score += 50
            else:
                    score += 0

    return score

guess_1 = input('guess the first 2 letters corresponding to letters 1 and2 of the unkown word!: ')
print('Your guess and score were: ', guess, score)
```

Comment: please break down your problem to smaller parts and post a small reproducible example with required input and desired output. I bet you can describe what you are struggling with in no more than 4 lines of code.

Comment: And fix your indentation please

Comment: I removed all code except my most recent attempt.  As for indenting, I changed all that I knew were out of place.  I know it's something I need to work on.

Comment: Im not exactly sure of how you want this to work but did you mean for the `for loop` and `return` statement to be in some kind of function?

Comment: Yes sorry, the function for this part will be a compute_score(guess,position,word) function.  So for example, if I type compute_score('abc', 0, 'share') the score will be 10 as there is an 'a' in the word 'shape'.  But if its compute_score('bac', 1, 'blanket') the score will be 70 as the 'b' is in the correct position, and the 'a' and 'b' guesses are in the word.

Answer (score 1):

You're closer than you think toward completing step 1. You already have code for inputting the guess, now you just need to do the same thing for inputting the selected word. You might want to change the input messages though:

```
word = input('Choose your unknown word: ')
guess = input('guess the first 2 letters corresponding to letters 1 and2 of the unkown word!: ')
```

And that's it for step 1!

Steps 2 and 3 are going to require more work, because theree are some issues with your `compute_score` function. The first problem is that you are immediately overwriting the values of some of the parameters you passed in:

```
def compute_score(guess,position,word):
    """ Doc string """

    score = 0
    right_position_value = 100
    wrong_position_value = 20
    guess = input()  <-- This will prompt the user for input a third time, and then
                         overwrite their initial guess with this one. 
    position = pos for char in guess  <-- Same problem here
    word_position = pos for char in word
```

If you reassign these variables before you even use them, then there was no point to making them parameters to the function in the first place. But even if you fixed this, you would still get an error from this:

```
word_position = pos for char in word
```

I see what you're trying to do, but if you're going to iterate through each letter of the word in the following `for` loop anyway, you might as well just calculate the position of each letter in the loop as well. Here's a neat little trick you can use in your `for` loop to do just that:

```
for idx, char in enumerate(word):
```

This gives you not only each letter of the word (`char`), but it also gives you the count of iterations the loop has made (`idx`). For example:

```
>>> word = 'shape'
>>> for idx, char in enumerate(word):
...     print(idx)
...
0
1
2
3
4
```

You can use this iteration count value as the letter's position, hopefully that should help you figure out step 3 (Admittedly I'm still not quite sure of the purpose of the `position` parameter or how the position-guessing rules work)

For step 2, you're also pretty close. Currently you're checking if the two letter guess is *anywhere* in the selected word. To only check the first 2 letters you can use a substring of the word. In Python this is done by "slicing" all but the first 2 letters of the word during the check:

```
for char in word:
    if char in guess[:2]:
            score += 10
```

And boom there ya go.

However, I'd just like you to know that there are some other problems in your code, the main one being that the `guess` and `score` variables in the last line aren't defined anywhere, and that you never actually call the `compute_score` function. In your last line you should call it like this:

```
word = input('Choose your unknown word: ')
guess = input('guess the first 2 letters corresponding to letters 1 and2 of the unkown word!: ')

print('Your guess and score were: ', guess, calculate_score(guess, 0, word))
```

In the example I just passed in `0` as `position` because the game's position rules are still lost on me.  I can edit this if you give a more detailed explanation, though.

Comment: Hi Mat.  Thank you very much for your help!
I'll try and explain the purpose of the code more clearly:
Step 1 the user will guess 2 letters corresponding to the first two letters of the unknown word. They'll get 10 points for each guessed letter that is in the word (regardless of position), and 50 points for any letter guessed that is in the correct position.
Step 2 the user guesses 3 letters corresponding to the first 3 letters of the unknown word.
Step 3, the user guesses 3 letters for letter 2-4...step 4, 3 letter guess for 3-5 ect.I'll try my best to include the inx for loop.

Comment: I was planning on making a guessprompt(step,length) function as well to ask the user for input.  For example
 >>>guess = guessprompt(0,2)
'Guess 2 letters regarding letters 1 to 2 of the unknown word: '
But I think I should be able to work that out once I have the computescore function down.  
the computescore(guess,step,selectedword) function should work like this:
>>>computescore(abc, 0, 'bridge')
10
10 (guessed letter b, but not the correct position.

Comment: What about `compute_score('abc', 1, 'bridge')`, `compute_score('abc', 2, 'bridge')`, `compute_score('abc', 3, 'bridge')`, `compute_score('abc', 4, 'bridge')`, and `compute_score('abc', 5, 'bridge')`? Are they any different from `compute_score('abc', 0, 'bridge')`, and why/why not? Should `compute_score('bac', 0, 'bridge')`, `compute_score('bac', 1, `bridge`)`, and `compute_score('bac', 2, `bridge`)` all return 60 points? And why should `compute_score('bac', 1, 'blanket')` return 70 points if the position parameter is 1 and not 0?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion.The position value will be the step in the game. So step 0 involves guessing letters 1-2, step 1 involves guessing letters 1-3, step 2..letters 2-4,(2,3,4)..step 3.. letters 3-5, step 4-letters 4-6. So compute_score(abc,1,bridge) is pretty much seeing if 'abc' are in 'bri'.  A 'b' is in their guess, and the word, but not the correct position so they get 10 points.  If it was (abc, 3, bridge)->becomes is 'abc' in 'idg', so they'd get 0 points.  Likewise if it was (bac, 0, bridge), it is seeing if 'bac' is in 'bri', so they'd get 50 points for having the correct position.